# How to make use of parallelism to speed up conditional counting?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I would like to speed up the bottleneck of my code using parallelism in Python3. My code loops over a nested list of tuples and outputs a conditional count if a particular tuple is in the inner list (regardless of tuple frequency within the inner list).

I've tried replacing loops with generator expressions. I also tried the len() approach.

My current best attempt is:

```py
 xy_count = sum(i for tuple_list in nested_list if tuple([x,y]) in tuple_list)
```

How do I use Python3's standard parallelism libraries like concurrent futures to speed up this line?

Comment: You can start by reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html). Keep in mind that `concurrent.futures` doesn't necessarily provide _parallelism_: for example, `ThreadPoolExecutor` provides _concurrency_, which won't speed up CPU-bound tasks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accellerate *multiple*, *identical* calculations is by using a `multiprocessing.Pool` or a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`.

However, since your question is tagged with `jupyter-notebook`, the above mentioned objects might not work, *especially* on ms-windows.
This has to do with the way Python has to start new processes on that operating system.

So, if you want to use `multiprocessing.Pool` or `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` on ms-windows, it is best to do that from a script. Take careful note of the [programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines). These are for `multiprocessing` but they apply to `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` as well, since that is based on multiprocessing.